# how to display againt each id its all specifications in php

Tags: php, mysql

i have a table like this

```
C_number      Pkg_type
03212889438    calls
03212889438    sms
03215919448    Crbt
03215919448    Ivr
03215919448    call
```

and i want output as

```
C_number      Pkg_type
03212889438   Calls,sms
03215919448   Crbt,ivr,call
```

my query is:

```
<?php 
$s = "SELECT distinct(C_number),Pkg_type as pkg FROM packages group by C_number";

$results = mysql_query($s);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results))
{

  echo  $row['C_number'];

  echo  $row['pkg'];
}

 ?>
```

but this query only display against each number only one of its pkg not all.. what should i do?

is there any way to do it without group_concat.. i mean i dont want to write anythng before pkg_type as it will distrb my code later on.. please guide me if u ppl have nay idea

Comment: DISTINCT is not a function, and in any case, it's not what want - see below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SELECT c_number1 , GROUP_CONCAT( pkg_type ) as pkg FROM tablename GROUP BY c_number

Answer (score 5):

Use the MySql specific [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) aggregate function.

Your query with the above function:

```
$s = "SELECT C_number,group_concat(Pkg_type) as pkg FROM packages group by C_number";
```

Comment: You're welcome, however, I wouldn't have minded if you accepted my answer instead of the later one :)

Comment: is there any way to do it without group_concat.. i mean i dont want to write anythng before pkg_type as it will distrb my code later on.. please guide me if u have nay idea

Answer (score 0):

What I personally would do is create a list of c_number's. Then use a prepared statement to retrieve all pkg values per c_number, as it is generally fast if you re-use the same prepared query.

Zoltán's solution seems better though.

Comment: If you are not working with MySQL, then you definetely have to do some sort of client-side handling, because AFAIK none of the other bigger DB platforms support such an aggregate function.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below query :

SELECT `c_number` , GROUP_CONCAT( `pkg_type` ) as pkg 
FROM packages
GROUP BY `c_number`